# How to create a folder but not subscribe it in Dovecot's Sieve?

Tags: dovecot, sieve

I have Sieve rule:

```
 if header :contains "subject" ["TOP-SECRET"] {
    setflag "\\Seen";
    fileinto :create "Hidden-Folder";
    stop;
}
```

based on which anything what includes `TOP-SECRET` in the subject is moved to the `hidden-folder` and set as read.

Is there any way to set that `Hidden-Folder` as not subscribed (hidden from the folder list) via sieve? Or how "pipe" which account subscriptions file must to be edited by a script?

Comment: The "subscriptions" file (in user Maildir) save the folders subscribed by the user. The Hidden-Folder can be added by the user with its mail software

Comment: I know that but I need to set up that folder to be "hidden" (not subscribed) by default not by a mailbox user.

Comment: I think you can't but I will read the other answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I have got desired functionality to work via piping it to an external script.

Sieve code looks like:

```
if envelope :matches "To" "*@*" {
  set "recipient" "${0}";
}

     if header :contains "subject" ["TOP-SECRET"] {
        setflag "\\Seen";
        fileinto :create "Hidden-Folder";
        pipe "my-script" ["${recipient}"]; 
        stop;
    }
```

then sieve-pipe `my-script` code looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

mbox=$1
result=`find /mnt/var/mailboxes -type d -name $mbox`
perl -pi -e 's/Hidden-Folder//g' $result/subscriptions
```

Side note - be sure that owner of all mailboxes in `/mnt/var/mailboxes` is Dovecot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an option to configure such behavior -- neither in Sieve nor in the Pigeonhole or Dovecot configuration.

But I can propose a workaround: Create an unsubscribed, hidden folder and put subdirectories into that.

If you create a folder like `Hidden-Folder` which you define as unsubscribed (either manually or using `doveadm`), an action `fileinto :create "Hidden-Folder.Foo" will create the folder`foo`inside`Hidden-Folder`, but not automatically subscribe it.

You could of course also use [`vnd.dovecot.execute`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dovecot/pigeonhole/master/doc/rfc/spec-bosch-sieve-extprograms.txt) and run `doveadm mailbox unsubscribe` to unsubscribe the mailbox after running `fileinto`, or even create the mailbox (without subscribing it) before filing the message. I'm not really having a good feeling executing system commands through Sieve, though; even if it's only a predefined command with well-checked parameters.